# ACPI BIOS Error trying to boot Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on ASUS ROG STRIX Z790-E MB

Tags: boot, uefi, asus, bios, acpi

I just bought and built a computer and am having trouble booting into Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. It's all relatively new hardware and I can't find much online about it, except for slightly different errors.
Here's some of the hardware info:

Motherboard: ASUS ROG STRIX Z790-E GAMING WIFI (BIOS v. 0401)

CPU: Intel i7-13700K

The GPU is an NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4080 but I haven't even gotten it to boot, much less install drivers for the graphics card

Anyways, The installation seems to go fine, also selecting "Try Ubuntu" boots up fine as well. However when I try to boot into the fresh Ubuntu install, I get this terminal output flashing at me (I'm transcribing this since I can't just copy it, not bothering with the numbers at the start of each line)

```
[  20.XXXXXX] usb 1-5.3: device descriptor read/64, error -110
/dev/nvme0n1p2: clean, 215953/122060992 files, 11135943/488247296 blocks
[  21.XXXXXX] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[  22.XXXXXX] mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[  22.XXXXXX] 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529) 
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object (\_SB.PC00.PREG1.PEGP._DSM.USRG], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210730/dsfield-184)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, CreateBufferField failure (20210730/dswload2-477)
[  22.XXXXXX] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.PEG1.PEGP._DSM due to previous error (AE_ALREADY_EXISTS) (20210730/psparse-529)
```

I can't seem to get into grub2 either to try other boot options, although this was an issue when I was trying Ubuntu GamePack 20.04, (which did successfully install and boot, but it was having network issues), so I'm wondering if that's an issue with my keyboard or the BIOS not letting me shift into it.

When I tried booting with the BIOS's Compatibility Support Module, my BIOS stopped booting altogether and I had to reset the motherboard. I'm thinking those settings have more to do with the BIOS boot and not the OS boot.

Anyways, let me know if I've left out any critical information. Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You need UEFI boot. And it will be easier to install proprietary nVidia driver with UEFI Secure Boot off. When installing did you use Safe Boot and check to install restricted extras? That installs the correct nVidia driver from Ubuntu's repository. Also can you press escape just after vendor logo & before grub should appear? And boot recovery mode to terminal? With network on `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` You may need 22.10 to have newest kernel & drivers, but if live  installer of 22.04 works, then should be ok.

Comment: So I'm able to boot into recovery mode, get to the terminal, and install the ubuntu drivers. But as for the UEFI boot, the only way I see how to do that is to enable CSM and setting the Boot Device Control to UEFI only. Doing this and rebooting causes the machine to power on but no input is sent to the monitor and I can't do anything. The only way out is to press the Clear CMOS button to reset the MB. Not sure if there's some other way to UEFI boot?

Comment: I had an old Asus z97. I think that was also backwards in logic that you had to go into CSM which is for BIOS boot to turn on UEFI boot. New laptop now do not even have CSM mode. Motherboards will probably keep it for a long time. Do you have a setting in UEFI for control of which graphics is used? My z97 used auto and just worked. Not sure what settings they now have. Check your manual.

Comment: there's no control, although I did find that booting in UEFI was giving me no display because, with the Nvidia drivers I installed, it routed the display through the GPU. Everything seems to be in order. Thanks so much for the help!